# Some characterization of Mahlo cardinals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Following the well-known characterization of supercompact cardinals by Magidor, in [our paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10125) we have defined the notion of a $\kappa$-Magidor model, for supercompact cardinal $\kappa$.
I defined a similar notion for a Mahlo cardinal $\kappa$, and proved the following easy characterization.

> Fact. The following are equivalent for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$.
>
> 1. $\kappa$ is Mahlo.
> 2. For every regular $\lambda>\kappa$, and for every $x\in H_\lambda$, there is $M\prec H_\lambda$ such that $\kappa,x\in M$, $M\cap\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, and that $M$ is closed under sequences of length less than $M\cap \kappa$.

This fact was also proved by Holy, Lucke and Njegomir in their [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06103). However, I believe that this was stated  implicitly in Feng's [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274861).

I believe that many logicians are aware of the above fact. I was wondering, to whom I should attribute this? Was such result appeared somewhere else? Is it folklore?

Comment: It strikes me as folklore.  I know that Saharon and I were using this on a forcing project back in the late 90s, and it was just one of those things we knew.

Comment: @ToddEisworth, I see, Thank you!